# Is there a way to make this asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

This  seems like an easy one and that I'm just missing something obvious, but a little background:

I am making a mock "bug reporting" web app. The app has two types of user: "user" and "engineer". Upon signup the user is assigned a type, and it's saved in a firebase collection "users" under a firebase unique identifier "uid".

Upon login to the web app, a firebase user object for the logged in user is retrieved from firebase. This object has "user.uid" on it.

In order to grab the user type (saved as userType in the firebase document) I need to take that user.uid and send the uid part to a react hook I have made. This hook then fetches the document with that uid and returns the userType.

I've made the following dummy file to demonstrate.

```
import {React, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { useAuthContext } from '../../hooks/useAuthContext'
import { useDocument } from '../../hooks/useDocument'




export default function User() {
    const { user } = useAuthContext();
    console.log("uid: " + user.uid)

    const id = user.uid;
    console.log("id: " + id)

    let { document, error } = useDocument("users", id)
    console.log("userType: " + document.userType)

  return (
    <div>


    </div>
  )
}
```

Now the problem I have is that "user" isn't initalised from Context in time before the program tries to go fetch it, using a uid that, again, isn't initialised in time.

**Basically I just need a way to delay using the useDocument hook, but I can't make hooks asynchronous. My async skills aren't my strongest point, to say the least.**

Any help is massively appreciated, I've spent so many hours trying to crack this.

EDIT: Upon request, here is the useDocument hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { projectFirestore } from "../firebase/config"


export const useDocument = (collection, id) => {

  const [document, setDocument] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  // realtime document data
  useEffect(() => {
    const ref = projectFirestore.collection(collection).doc(id)

    const unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      // need to make sure the doc exists & has data

      if(snapshot.data()) {
        setDocument({...snapshot.data(), id: snapshot.id})
        setError(null)
        
      }
      else {
        setError('No such document exists')
      }
    }, err => {
      console.log(err.message)
      setError('failed to get document')
    })

    // unsubscribe on unmount
    return () => unsubscribe()

  }, [collection, id])

  return { document, error }
}
```

Comment: What is happening in the `useDocument` hook? I guess you have two options; defer the `useDocument` hook until the user is loaded by adding an `enabled` argument or to use the `useDocument` hook in a nested component.

Comment: Chris is right, and another potential design would be to initialize the auth context with the full user object instead of just its id, so that you have the type ready as soon as a user logs in.

Comment: Chris - I'll try the enabled argument solution first. I'm not familiar with it at all but I'll have a root around the docs (never did anyone any harm).

Emile - Unfortunately the user object which firebase returns only has certain key:value pairs attached and most "custom" fields that you create aren't part of that, otherwise that would be absolutely spot on.

Comment: What I meant is that nothing is preventing you from doing both requests in your auth context, before setting the values to indicate that the user is authenticated.

Comment: I see, unfortunately I've tried that, too and it's the same issue because it's just moving the problem somewhere else - still need the user.uid to initialise in time to go fetch the userType :(

Comment: So is there seriously no way to await data from a database request, then make a second request using a parameter from that data? This seems like madness, either that or I'm going mad.